# How to wait before mv command completes in unix?

Tags: command, zip

I need to zip some files, move zipped files to some other directory using  `mv` command and then remove all files from original location.
But in my case `rm` command is executing before `mv` command and failing `mv` command.

I tried below approaches but it didn't help.

Approach 1 :

```
$ zip -r foo.zip * &;  wait %1 && mv foo.zip mydir &; wait %1 && rm -rf *
```

Approach 2 :

```
[ zip -r foo.zip *] || {mv foo.zip mydir && rm -rf *}
```

Comment: You want to "move zipped files to some other directory using mv command and then remove all files from original location". Why? `mv` copies and then removes from the source location. You don't need `rm` anymore. PS : please have a look at the difference between `;` and `&&`

Comment: @schaiba He's removing the files he zipped. The "zipped files" he's _moving_ are the ones in the archive, I believe.

Comment: Why are you running `zip` and `mv` in the background???

Comment: @Schaiba : It's correct. This is what i mean , "move zipped files to some other directory using mv command and then remove all files from original location". But somehow rm -rf *; getting executed before mv command. Checking exit status with &&, did not help here.

Comment: The exit status check is done with `echo $?`.

Comment: Its working fine after adding echo $? . Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You're complicating it.

If `zip` exits with an exit status that reflects success or failure, you can simply do

```
$ zip -r foo.zip . && mv foo.zip mydir && rm -rf *
```

However, I really hope `mydir` is not located in the current directory, or it would get deleted by the `rm -rf *`.   In general when using `rm -rf`, I'd think both two and three times before I put a `*` after it!!  In fact, I can count the number of times I've done that (`rm -rf *`) in the last year on the fingers of one hand. I would never put it in a script.

Safer way (assuming `mydir` is actually a path to somewhere else than in the current directory):

```
$ zip -r --move --test foo.zip . && mv foo.zip mydir
```

Or even

```
$ zip -r --move --test mydir/foo.zip .
```

Note the use of `.` (dot) rather than `*`.  With `*` any file with a `-` as the first character in its name would be interpreted as a command line switch to `zip`.  Test this by creating a file called `--encrypt`, for example:

```
$ touch -- --encrypt
$ zip -r --move --test ../test.zip *
Enter password:

$ rm -- --encrypt
```

Comment: You can aggregate the `zip` and the `rm` into `zip -r --move --test foo.zip *`

Comment: @xhienne : mydir is on another file system. I need to clean current directory with rm  -rf *; after moving zip to mydir.  Not able to see any zip files transferred on my dir as rm is deleting zipped file before mv complete.

Comment: @VijayShinde I don't understand your comment.